# how to find the indexes of a given key in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

What I need is to find the indexes of a given key in array of objects. for example, to combine the the values of objects with identical keys into one object with one key and the sum of its values, as shown below:

```
cart = [{id: 123, quantity: 3}, {id: 456, quantity: 2}, {id: 123, quantity: 2}, {id: 456, quantity: 4}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and bit ugly solution is:

```js
cart = [{id: 123, quantity: 3}, {id: 456, quantity: 2}, {id: 123, quantity: 2}, {id: 456, quantity: 4}];
newCart = [];
for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
  found = false;
  for (var j = 0; j < newCart.length; j++) {
    if (cart[i].id == newCart[j].id) {
      newCart[j].quantity += cart[i].quantity;
      found = true;
    }
  }
  if (!found) {
    newCart.push(cart[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
    const cart = [{id: 123, quantity: 3}, {id: 456, quantity: 2}, {id: 123, quantity: 2}, {id: 456, quantity: 4}]
    const sumOfId = (id) => cart.filter(c => c.id === id).reduce((a, b) => a + b.quantity, 0);
    const cartProducts = cart.filter((v,i,a)=>a.findIndex(t=>(t.id === v.id))===i);
    const newCart = []; 
    for(let i = 0; i < cartProducts.length; i++) {
        const id = cartProducts[i].id;
        newCart.push(id, sumOfId(id));
    }
```

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark it as accepted answer :)